# Can't figure how to web-scraping using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the info below from some web page. This is the full code:

```
<tr class="owner">
   <td id="P184" class="ownerP" colspan="4">
      <ul>
         <li><span class="detailType">name:</span><span class="detail">merry/span></li>
         <li><a title="sendmessage" class="sendMessageLink" onclick="return openSendMessage('/sendMessage.php',20205" href="" tabindex="0"><span></span>sendmessage</a>&nbsp;<span class="remark_soft">(by pm system)</span></li>
         <li><span class="detailType">phone 1</span><a class="detail" href="tel:0387362531">0387362531</a></li>
         <li><span class="detailType"></span></li>
      </ul>
   </td>
</tr>
```

I want to only get this info (the phone number):

> ```
> <a class="detail" href="tel:0387362531">0387362531</a>
> ```

Here is my code, but it doesn't work:

```
 for details in soup.find_all(attrs= {"class": "detail"}):
    re_res = re.search(r"tel:\('.*?',(\d+)\)", details['href'])
    print(re_res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close, here you go:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<tr class="owner"><td id="P184" class="ownerP" colspan="4"><ul>
            <li><span class="detailType">name:</span><span class="detail">merry/span></li>
            <li><a title="sendmessage" class="sendMessageLink" onclick="return openSendMessage('/sendMessage.php',20205" href="" tabindex="0"><span></span>sendmessage</a>&nbsp;<span class="remark_soft">(by pm system)</span></li><li><span class="detailType">phone 1</span><a class="detail" href="tel:0387362531">0387362531</a></li><li><span class="detailType"></span></li>
</ul></td></tr>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for details in soup.find_all(attrs= {"class": "detail"}):
    if "href" in details.attrs and re.search("^tel:", details.attrs["href"]):
        print(details.text)
```

Output:

```
0387362531
```

I'm simply looking through the details list you've made and if I find one that has and `href` and that `href` starts with `tel:` then print that value out.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `soup.find_all(attrs= {"class": "detail"})` by `soup.find_all('a', attrs= {"class": "detail"})[0]` in order to avoid having the `span` too in `details`.

Moreover your regex does not work, this one should work `tel:(\d+)`. But rather than using a regex why not just getting `a` tag text by doing `details.text` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the element type `a` to [find_all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) and your regex `tel:\('.*?',(\d+)\)` tries to match opening and closing parenthesis `\(` and `\)` which are not in the `href`.

You could update your regex to [`tel:(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/kWNJco/1) to match `tel:` followed by one or more digits in a capturing group (group 1) which you can retrieve with `re_res.group(1)`

For example:

```
for details in soup.find_all('a', attrs= {"class": "detail"}):
    re_res = re.search(r"tel:(\d+)", details['href'])
    print(re_res.group(1))  # 0387362531
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same result without using regex. In that case, try the below approach:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<tr class="owner"><td id="P184" class="ownerP" colspan="4"><ul>
            <li><span class="detailType">name:</span><span class="detail">merry/span></li>
            <li><a title="sendmessage" class="sendMessageLink" onclick="return openSendMessage('/sendMessage.php',20205" href="" tabindex="0"><span></span>sendmessage</a>&nbsp;<span class="remark_soft">(by pm system)</span></li><li><span class="detailType">phone 1</span><a class="detail" href="tel:0387362531">0387362531</a></li><li><span class="detailType"></span></li>
</ul></td></tr>
"""
```

Using `.select()`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
for telephone in soup.select("a[href^='tel:']"):
    if "detail" in telephone['class']:
        print(telephone.text)
```

Or with `.find_all()`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
for telephone in soup.find_all("a",class_="detail"):
    if telephone['href'].startswith('tel:'):
        print(telephone.text)
```

They both produce the same output:

```
0387362531
```